# awk transpose specific row to column and group them

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have the below data in a stdout:

```
09:13:32 19.2 cpu(1)
09:13:32 15.6 cpu(2)
09:13:32 16.7 cpu(3)
09:13:32 17.1 cpu(6)
09:13:32 17.1 cpu(7)
09:13:32 16.9 cpu(8)
09:13:32 16.7 cpu(9)
09:13:39 13.0 cpu(1)
09:13:39 9.2 cpu(2)
09:13:39 9.1 cpu(3)
09:13:39 7.1 cpu(6)
09:13:39 27.1 cpu(7)
09:13:39 46.9 cpu(8)
09:13:39 36.7 cpu(9)
```

Trying to convert this to something like below.

```
['Time', 'cpu(1)', 'cpu(2)', 'cpu(3)', 'cpu(6)', 'cpu(7)', 'cpu(8)', 'cpu(9)'],
['09:13:32',  19.2, 15.6, 16.7, 17.1, 17.1, 16.9, 16.7],
['09:13:39', 13.0, 9.2, 9.1, 7.1, 27.1, 46.9, 36.7]
```

In other words, I need the original data to be aligned with Google visualization line chart format as stated here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

I am trying to achieve this using awk and need some inputs.

```
awk '{ for(N=1; N<=NF; N+=2) print $N, $(N+1); }' | awk 'BEGIN{q="\047"; printf "["q"Time"q","q"CPU"q"],"}/master/{q="\047"; printf "["q$10q"," $3"],"}' | sed 's/,$//'"
```

Note: I can change the original data columns like below

```
Time CPU(%) CPU Number
```

**OR**

```
CPU(%) CPU Number Time
```

Comment: do you know all times will be for the same day, or do you need to worry about a series of data rolling over/past midnight? what should be stored in an ouput column if a data point is missing for one or more cpu entries, or do you know for a fact that *all* cpus will be present for each time entry?  what version of `awk` (`awk --version`) are you using?

Comment: do you know for a fact that the data will always be sorted by time and cpu #, or do we need to worry about sorting the inputs?

Comment: @markp-fuso, Each file will have a 6 hours of data from 9am to 3pm local time and below is my awk version 20121220 (FreeBSD)

Comment: @markp-fuso, I can modify columns as we need. No restriction for that. CPU Number / cpu(*) keeps repeating for 6 hours with each loop timing for 7 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk for any number of times and any number of cpus, and will work even if you don't have data for some time+cpu combinations, as long as the input isn't so massive that it can't all fit in memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ", "
}
!seenTimes[$1]++ {
    times[++numTimes] = $1
}
!seenCpus[$3]++ {
    cpus[++numCpus] = $3
}
{
    vals[$1,$3] = $2
}
END {
    printf "[\047%s\047%s", "Time", OFS
    for ( cpuNr=1; cpuNr<=numCpus; cpuNr++ ) {
        cpu = cpus[cpuNr]
        printf "\047%s\047%s", cpu, (cpuNr<numCpus ? OFS : "]")
    }

    for ( timeNr=1; timeNr<=numTimes; timeNr++ ) {
        time = times[timeNr]
        printf ",%s[\047%s\047%s", ORS, time, OFS
        for ( cpuNr=1; cpuNr<=numCpus; cpuNr++ ) {
            cpu = cpus[cpuNr]
            val = vals[time,cpu]
            printf "%s%s", val, (cpuNr<numCpus ? OFS : "]")
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
['Time', 'cpu(1)', 'cpu(2)', 'cpu(3)', 'cpu(6)', 'cpu(7)', 'cpu(8)', 'cpu(9)'],
['09:13:32', 19.2, 15.6, 16.7, 17.1, 17.1, 16.9, 16.7],
['09:13:39', 13.0, 9.2, 9.1, 7.1, 27.1, 46.9, 36.7]
```

Comment: Then after accepting an answer to this question, post a new question with that information and an example that would show/test that scenario if you can't figure out how to do it after reading/using the answer you accept to this question. [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are highly discouraged on this forum.

Comment: I get this error when I try to create a new question --> You can’t post new questions right now

Comment: Added in other forum: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/725557/awk-transpose-specific-row-to-column-and-group-them